# Deploy notebook in IBM Watson

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have a python notebook in **IBM Watson Studio** for a time series forecasting purpose.

it takes two input data

1. MAX
2. MIN

and it returns two lists of data having 10 steps ahead prediction of both `MAX` and `MIN`.

I want to make it available for an external application. I have searched for the solution like API creation but didn't get any source. can anyone suggest me the proper way or helpful resources to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got the solution of my own question through my 2 days of research and attempts. Nobody gave me any solution so I thought that it would be posted here for future references.

Here, I have added my practical experience so that it might be a long answer.

**1. Why IBM Notebook?**

We choose a notebook instead of available models if we need more customization. we will get most of the models that are not available in the built-in models

**2. Ways to do that?**

As per my enquiry, I found two ways to do that

- Deploy it as python function ( *Worked for me* )
- Deploy it with the help of jupyter notebook, IBM Cloud and Github See this [tutorial](https://github.com/ibm/predictive-model-on-watson-ml)

**3. Deploy it as python function** [[source]](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-deploy-functions.html)

- Wrap up all your functionalities under a single function (**Step 1**). like it takes input and returns the output.
- In each call, the variables or data structures you have in the code will lose the data. so avoid these items in your python function and manage it in your application.
- Another important point is that if you want to import libraries you have to include it as a subprocess inside the main function Because of the difference in testing environments and deployed environment. you can do it by simply adding like this
- *Sample Format python Function*

  ```
  def my_deployable_function():

     import subprocess
     subprocess.check_output( "pip install ipython--user",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True )

      def score( payload ):

         num1=int(payload["values"][0])
         num2=int(payload["values"][1])  
         ans=num1+num2

      return ans
  ```

  *Here, the `payload` is the data you passed to the python function from the API and `ans` is the output
- *Test the Function*

  ```
  function_result = my_deployable_function()( { "values" : [ 100,200] } )
  print( function_result )
  ```

  *Input `payload` is a `dictionary`. as per your need, you can add the elements but make sure that you are *not changing the structure* ie, Everything Should be under a single root element here it is *values*.
- *output*

  ```
  300
  ```
- As you follow (**Step 2**) in [source](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-deploy-functions.html) you need credentials, if you have any problem with existing credentials then create a new one because older one may be expired.
- If your plan is Lite you are not able to perform more than 5 Deployments (**Step 3**). so make it count. if it exceeded, either create a new service by deleting existing service or delete older deployments.
- If you are creating a new service, check it in Project settings is it associated with your project or not. otherwise, the credential will work only in the IBM Watson, not through REST API (**Step 4**).

Follow the official documentation and keep these instructions to save your time.